# Unable to start jmeter in Mac using jmeter.sh file

Tags: shell, java, jmeter

I am facing a problem in starting JMeter 5.1.1 in my Mac.  I have installed the jmeter zip file from https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi and unzipped it. 
Then I went to `jmeter/bin` on my terminal and tried the command `sh jmeter.sh`.

This throws the below errors:

```
jmeter.sh: line 98: [: : integer expression expected
./jmeter: line 128: [: : integer expression expected
./jmeter: line 192: /usr/bin/java:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

java version am using is 1.8.0_171

Can anyone suggest what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Line 98 of `jmeter.sh` and line 128 of `jmeter` both look like

```
if [ "$CURRENT_VERSION" -gt "$MINIMAL_VERSION" ]; then
```

Check what output you get from

```
"${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" -version
```

and proceed accordingly.